# SQL query not returning expected results after LEFT JOIN (schema & pics included)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I created a query earlier which concatenates staff members associated with a customer. There is only ever 2 customers assigned to each customer. My problem is after the query is executed, for each customer, it associates ALL staff members with each customer, not 2. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT C.customer_ID, C.l_Name AS Surname, 
    C.f_Name AS 'First Name', C.travel_Date,
    T.tour_Name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(S.f_Name, S.l_Name ) AS Staff_Concat
    FROM Customers AS C 

    LEFT JOIN Tour AS T ON C.tour_ID = T.tour_ID
    LEFT JOIN Staff_Day AS SD ON C.tour_ID = SD.tour_ID
    LEFT JOIN Staff_Day AS SD_2 ON SD_2.sd_Date = C.travel_Date 
    LEFT JOIN Staff AS S ON SD.staff_ID = S.staff_ID

    WHERE 
    C.travel_Date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
    AND C.travel_Date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59'

    AND C.customer_ID NOT IN (SELECT O.customer_ID 
    FROM Customers AS C, Orders AS O 
    WHERE C.travel_Date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
    AND C.travel_Date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59' AND C.customer_ID = O.customer_ID )
    GROUP BY C.customer_ID, Surname, 'First Name', C.travel_Date, T.tour_Name
```

This query successfully returns the correct amount of passengers. However, it is returning incorrect data for staff members. There should only be 2 staff members assigned to each passenger. This query seems to return all staff members for each customer. The result I'm getting is:

```
6166    customer_Name   2014-07-08 Wildthing    Staff1, Staff2, staff3...staff10
```

The expected result should be:

```
6166    customer_Name   2014-07-08 Wildthing    Staff1, staff2
```

Attached images for the Staff, Staff_Day and Tour table:

Staff_Day

[image: Staff Day Table]

Staff

[image: Staff Table]

Tour

[image: Tour Table]

Attached is structure for the Customers, Staff, Staff_Day and Tour table:

```
Table structure for table Customers
Column  Type    Null    Default
customer_ID int(11) No  
f_Name  varchar(30) Yes NULL
l_Name  varchar(30) No  
address varchar(100)    No  
suburb  varchar(30) No  
state   varchar(30) No  
country varchar(30) No  
postcode    varchar(30) No  
email   varchar(50) No  
phone   varchar(20) No  
child_1 varchar(30) Yes NULL
child_2 varchar(30) Yes NULL
child_3 varchar(30) Yes NULL
child_4 varchar(30) Yes NULL
travel_Date datetime    No  
signature   text    No  
terms   tinyint(1)  No  
interested_video    tinyint(1)  Yes 0
specials    tinyint(1)  Yes NULL
tour_ID int(11) Yes NULL
updated timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Table structure for table Staff
Column  Type    Null    Default
f_Name  varchar(30) No  
l_Name  varchar(30) No  
comm_Value  int(3)  No  
staff_Type  varchar(50) No  
staff_ID    int(11) No  
bus_ID  int(11) No  

Table structure for table Staff_Day
Column  Type    Null    Default
sd_ID   int(11) No  
staff_ID    int(4)  No  
tour_ID int(4)  No  
sd_Date datetime    No  

Table structure for table Tour
Column  Type    Null    Default
tour_Name   varchar(30) No  
tour_ID int(11) No  
bus_ID  int(11) No
```

I have been told there may be an issue in the JOIN part of the SQL query. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if this is a repost. I have done my research but I'm just running into brick walls now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a very slight restructure of your query.  You don't need two queries to the staff-day table on both ID and another by date, that was creating a Cartesian result on you.  Instead, use the one table join on BOTH PARTS, and instead of hard-coding the from/to date compared to the staff-day table.  You can just do a DATE_ADD() and be LESS than 1 full day... unless you are storing time portions on the travel date, then you would be better to do based on the date matching regardless of the time.

So, the first left-join on tour for the description, no problem.
Second on the staff-day and then staff based on matching tour AND date.

Finally, you have a NOT IN (subselect).  I changed this to a join format too, but just to clarify.  It APPEARS you are trying to get a list of all customers who may have signed up for a given tour, but never actually placed and committed an order.  But.. what if someone signs up for other orders on different days for the same customer, they will have an order on file... but you are then forcing the qualifier on the customer travel date.  Without knowing more details behind the dates and orders table for exceptions...  I am not sure what other impacts may be exposed.

***EDIT***

Since you are still getting issues with Cartesian results (but doesn't make sense), change your joins to INNER JOINS, thus the tour IS and SHOULD BE known and valid

```
SELECT 
      C.customer_ID, 
      C.l_Name AS Surname, 
      C.f_Name AS 'First Name', 
      C.travel_Date,
      T.tour_Name, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(S.f_Name, S.l_Name ) AS Staff_Concat
   FROM 
      Customers AS C 
         JOIN Tour AS T 
            ON C.tour_ID = T.tour_ID
         JOIN Staff_Day AS SD 
            ON C.tour_ID = SD.tour_ID
           AND C.Travel_Date >= SD.sd_Date
           AND SD.sd_date < Date_add( C.Travel_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
            JOIN Staff AS S 
               ON SD.staff_ID = S.staff_ID
   WHERE 
          C.travel_Date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
      AND C.travel_Date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59'
      AND C.customer_ID NOT IN 
         ( SELECT 
                 C.customer_ID 
              FROM 
                 Customers AS C
                    JOIN Orders AS O 
                       ON C.customer_ID = O.customer_ID 
              WHERE 
                     C.travel_Date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' 
                 AND C.travel_Date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59' )
   GROUP BY 
      C.customer_ID, 
      Surname, 
      'First Name', 
      C.travel_Date, 
      T.tour_Name
```

Suggestion on restructure of tables.  I would have it more like...

Tours - generically
TourSpecific - specific unique ID that also has ID for the tour it is based on but also has the specific time slot being offered.  This way, when a customer signs up for the 10am vs 2pm tour, they would be assigned SpecificTourID, then you don't have to deal with timestamp comparisons.  Similarly, the staff for the particular day and time slot would have the SpecificTourID, then you will have less confusion and simpler queries.

Ex:

```
Tours
TourID   TourName
10       Jammin
11       Thriller
12       Thunderstruck
13       Wildthing

SpecificTours
SpecificTourID   TourID   TourDateTime
1                10       8/1/2014 8:00am
2                10       8/1/2014 1:15pm 
3                10       8/4/2014 8:00am
4                10       8/4/2014 1:15pm

Customers
CustomerID   FirstName  LastName
1            Bill       Board
2            Eileen     Dover
3            Seymore    Hair

Orders
OrderID   CustomerID   SpecificTourID
1         1            1
2         2            1
3         1            4
```

StaffDay (similar approach, but using the specific tourID they are assigned

This way, the order for Order #2 is for specific tour 1 which is tour 10 which is Jammin.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DRapp. You are right that this query is to grab a list of customers who have NOT placed an order. But many thanks on modifying the subselect. I did give it a try and I still got unexpected results. While I did get the correct amount of rows for this particular day, for each customer that has a tour selected, it shows all staff members associated. Regardless if they have selected a tour or not, the staff members should pop up regardless.

Comment: @AkiraDawson, modified query to NOT use left-join, but inner JOINs.  The customer has a tour, it better be a valid ID to run with, and if a valid tour, I would expect your table of staff for a given day / tour also are valid.  This MIGHT eliminate your issue of the Cartesian result.

Comment: since you modified your query, it now only displays results that have a tour assigned to customer. I need the query to display customers regardless if they have been assigned a tour or not. The staff columns is still listing all staff members to assigned customer who have selected a tour, which still baffles me haha.

Comment: I add into the where clause @DRapp AND SD.sd_date >= '2014-07-08 00:00:00' AND SD.sd_date <= '2014-07-08 23:59:59' and now the staff members are displaying correctly. Except now I need to display the customers regardless if the have "trip take" selected. I thought a LEFT JOIN would accomplish this.

Comment: @AkiraDawson, your Staff-day table. You showed sample, but are there more for the same day with different staff, such as different people at a 10am, 12pm, 2pm, 4pm and alternating staff on those shifts?  If so, that may be why as you have all the people at different times and you are qualifying the join for the entire day, not the specific hour the person's tour is scheduled for.  But yes, go back to left-joins.

Comment: The times are used for something entirely different. The fact is I built the database to ensure all fields are filled out. I'm now going back to the client to inform him of his options. Either have tour_Name filled out to get associated staff names because the code example you gave does work, once tweaked. I thank you again for your help. Really, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AkiraDawson, I appreciate the accepted answer status, but mentioning going to your client of options.  I modified the end of my answer to show another approach to hopefully simplify even more.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
LEFT JOIN Staff_Day AS SD_2 ON SD_2.sd_Date = C.travel_Date
```

That's joining all the records from your example Staff_Day table, when it seems like you only want the ones with a particular tour_ID.  If there's no reason for that line, you can remove it entirely.  However, if you are trying to filter the Staff_Day table by date in addition to tour_ID, try replacing this:

```
LEFT JOIN Staff_Day AS SD ON C.tour_ID = SD.tour_ID
LEFT JOIN Staff_Day AS SD_2 ON SD_2.sd_Date = C.travel_Date
```

With this:

```
LEFT JOIN Staff_Day AS SD ON C.tour_ID = SD.tour_ID AND SD.sd_Date = C.travel_Date
```

That way, you're only joining the Staff_Day table once and will receive what I'm guessing are your desired results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did amend my SQL query but now nothing comes up for the staff column.